# Django: Group by model parameter and Count

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have 2 models:

```
class FaultType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And

```
class RunFault(models.Model):
    run = models.ForeignKey(Run, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fault_type = models.ForeignKey(FaultType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

I need to group all instances of RunFault by FaultType, and count them.

Preferably obtain a `dict`with structure (example):

```
faults = {
    "some_fault" = 7,
    "foo_fault" = 4,
    "bar_fault" = 13
}
```

(Where "blabla_fault" is FaultType.name)

Basically I need the `dict` key to be the `FaultType.name` and the value to be the count.

Right now I'm querying the DB like so:

```
faults = RunFault.objects.values('fault_type__name').order_by('fault_type').annotate(count=Count('fault_type__name'))
```

But that returns a `list` of `dicts` like so:

```
faults = [
    {"fault_type__name": "some_fault"},
    {"count": 7},
    {"fault_type__name": "foo_fault"},
    {"count": 4},
    {"fault_type__name": "bar_fault"},
    {"count": 13}
]
```

Where one `dict` has key `fault_type__name` and value `FaultType.name` and another `dict` has key `count` with the value being the actual count.

Hard to use them like that as I can't know which count belongs to which `FaultType`!

Is that the intended behaviour of `.annotate(count=Count('some_key'))` ?

Or am I doing the wrong query?

Comment: But that isn't what annotate gives you. It gives you a list of dictionaries, each one containing 'fault_type__name' and 'count'.

Comment: What isn't it gives me? The output I want, or the output I'm getting? Is it possible to extract the output I want through a queryset?

Comment: The output you show here is not the output of annotate. The code you have shown here would give you the output I described.